# Should I include my TOEFL ITP test score in my CV?

Tags: resume, certification

I intend to send my CV for a position and on the recruitment note was written that candidates who have a good knowledge of the English language are going to receive priority on the selection process.

I have a score of 643 on the TOEFL ITP test (Test of English as a Foreign Language), which indicates that I am on proficiency level. The problem is that "ITP tests are administered by an institution and for internal use" and I do not know if I am allowed to inform my test score (e.g. write it on my CV) to another institution.

I have not made another type of language test; therefore, I do not have a certification of proficiency (one like the TOEFL iBT would give me, because it is recognized by a large number of places, instead of being "valid" only for the institution that administered it).

If I do not include my TOEFL ITP score in the CV that I intend to send, do you think that I still may describe that I have a good knowledge of English? Is it a good idea to claim this without describing inside the CV that there is an evidence for it? Is it better to include my ITP test score than to occult it until asked for evidence?

Comment: "are administered by an institution and for internal use" Ask the institution?

Answer (score 2):

If I were in your shoes, I would not mention the English proficiency test score on my résumé. However, I would make sure that your CV and any other communications, such as a cover letter, are in impeccable English. These days, you can find online tools that would not only correct spelling but also grammar and style.

This should help you with the pre-interview phase. After that, you will need to prove that your spoken English is as good as your written English. At that point, the score will not help you except to give you the confidence that indeed, you are proficient in English.

The proof is in the pudding as they say...